# How to work with custom shopping cart in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have successfully built a shopping cart and everything works fine.
Here is what i want to accomplish:

1. if a user clicks on the add to cart button, it should add to the cart and refreshe the same page with the added item update.
2. If a user clicks on the image or View button, it displays the image of the item.

my problem is as follows:
 1. IF a user clicks on the add to cart button, it adds but redirects to the cart.php file (Which is not what i want, I want the page to reload with the added item update)
 2. I tried using:

```
$head = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
echo '<script>location.href="'.$head.'"</script>';
exit();
```

It seems to work well, when a user clicks add to cart button, but when a user clicks on image or click on view button, it refrehes the same page without allowing the user to view the image.

Below is my code.

```
//My custom shopping cart script

if (isset($_GET['pid'])) {
$pid = $_GET['pid'];
$wasFound = false;
$i = 0;
// If the cart session variable is not set or cart array is empty
if (!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1) { 
    // RUN IF THE CART IS EMPTY OR NOT SET
    $_SESSION["cart_array"] = array(0 => array("item_id" => $pid, "quantity" => 1));
} else {
    // RUN IF THE CART HAS AT LEAST ONE ITEM IN IT
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) { 
          $i++;
          while (list($key, $value) = each($each_item)) {
              if ($key == "item_id" && $value == $pid) {
                  // That item is in cart already so let's adjust its quantity using array_splice()
                  array_splice($_SESSION["cart_array"], $i-1, 1, array(array("item_id" => $pid, "quantity" => $each_item['quantity'] + 1)));
                  $wasFound = true;
              } // close if condition
          } // close while loop
       } // close foreach loop
       if ($wasFound == false) {
           array_push($_SESSION["cart_array"], array("item_id" => $pid, "quantity" => 1));
       }
}

  $head = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
//header("location: $head");
echo '<script>location.href="'.$head.'"</script>';
exit(); 
  }?>


    <!--My Products item Display-->
     <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="product-img product-img-brd">
                                <a href="pro_single.php?pid='.$id.'"><img class="full-width img-responsive" src="../../backend/'.$product_img.'" alt="'.$product_name.'"></a>
                                <a class="product-review" href="pro_single.php?pid='.$id.'">Quick review</a>

                                <a  class="add-to-cart" href="cart.php?pid='.$id.'" ><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Add to cart </a>

                                    <div class="product-price">
                                        <span class="title-price">$'.$price.'</span>            
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Comment: you can use use ajax to send item to cart and you wont need to reload the page

Comment: @JoshKisb  ok, how can i accomplish that?

Comment: is view image, add to cart, and the above code all one page?

Comment: @emekamba simply google `php ajax shopping cart` you will find lots of examples. javascript and ajax knowledge is required

Comment: there is no requirement to use AJAX if you just want to keep it simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of making it a link (with an anchor tag `<a>`), you'll want to write some JavaScript that will use one of the many different ways to call it with AJAX.

A simple version might look like this:

```
// update <a> in HTML
<a onclick="addToCart(' . $id . ')">Add to Cart</a>

// JavaScript
const addToCart = id => fetch('cart.php?pid=' + id).then(response => { /* do something with response here */ });
```

This is a simple version, but it gives you an idea. There are tons of guides for AJAX with all the different methods (I prefer the newer `fetch()`, but there is `jQuery.ajax()` and pure `XMLHttpRequest` too, amongst others).

When you use an anchor with a link, it's saying "go to this place", which isn't what you want. Using AJAX, you can pull down data without affecting the flow of the page itself.

Side note: ideally, change your `<a>` to a `<button>` as well. This will make it more semantic, since a button is a thing to click to do thing and an anchor is a link to another page.